# How to get RSS for iOS / XCode into NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rss, nsdictionary

I have the following code which worked fine in iOS but the structure of the XML-File has changed and I have no idea how to maintain my code :-( Anyone could help? If possible I'd like to change only this code because the rest should work fine. I see that the download itself works fine because receivedData contains 53k but I don't know how to transfer this into a NSDictionary now... I've read some other examples but they seem to use a totally different code and I don't want to rewrite too many parts of my application

```
- (NSDictionary *)getRSS: (NSString *)aKey
{
#define kURL @"https://developer.apple.com/news/rss/news.rss"
NSMutableString *finalURLStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString: kURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *receivedData = nil;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: finalURLStr]
                                  cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                              timeoutInterval: 60.0];
receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                     returningResponse: &response
                                                 error: &error];
if (receivedData) {
    id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: receivedData
                                                 options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                   error: &error];
    NSArray *resultArray = (jsonObj != [NSNull null] ? [jsonObj objectForKey: @"data"] : nil);
    // Extract record from response
    if ([resultArray count])
        return [resultArray objectAtIndex: 0];
} else {
    // Handle the error
}
return nil;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: your given url return xml output not json format and your code is read value of json formate.

Comment: OK, but how could I fix it?

Comment: not fix it in this code you use XML parsing code.@K232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link `https://developer.apple.com/news/rss/news.rss` is returning `RSS`, which is really a specification of `XML` format.

It seeme like Apple only delivers this particular feed in `rss` format, not in `json`, so to convert this link into `NSDictionary` in your app, the easiest sollution will be to use some kind of rss-parser. E.g. https://github.com/Bitnock/BNRSSFeedParser

/Knut

Comment: OK, thanks. As far as I remember, my UrL (the apple one was just an example) returned the XML included with some additionally JSON values, so the procedure above was necessary to extract the XML / RSS part from the JSON answer. I hoped there is a simple way to get the RSS into the NSDictionary, because the processing of the RSS-Elements already works fine. I just need to get the RSS into the NSDictionary....

Comment: Yes, some of Apples feeds has a parameter which you can use to get output in either xml or json, but it doesn't seeme to be available for this specific feed. I don't think there is an "one liner" to convert RSS into NSDictionary, but importing some kind of open source RSS parser  (there are tons of them on github) will make your task much easier.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said the returned feed is in XML format

If you don't want to use 3rd party libraries and instead want to parse it as JSON using the built in APIs, you could use a XML -> JSON middleman web service.

Google has one of these which is fast enough to not slow down your response too much.

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=<NUMBER OF ENTRIES>&q=<XML URL HERE>`

In your case it would be:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=25&q=https://developer.apple.com/news/rss/news.rss

Then you can parse it as JSON through the `responseData -> feed -> entries` keys, like so:

```
NSDictionary *jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *entries = jsonObj[@"responseData"][@"feed"][@"entries"];
NSLog(@"%@", entries);  // 25 rss entries
```

Comment: The API is no longer available. I guess google didnt make any money of it

Answer (score 0):

the link https://developer.apple.com/news/rss/news.rss return XML data so you need to parse it to use. The most common way to parse a XML string to any type of format data is use NSXMLParser.

I did write code for parse XML string in your case:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (strong) NSMutableString *mutableData;

@property NSMutableDictionary *item; // temp item

@property NSMutableArray *items; // items

@property NSInteger channelFlag; // flag == 1 isChannel, flag == 0 isItem;

@property NSMutableDictionary *channel;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

#define IsChannel 1
#define IsItem 0

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
#define kURL @"https://developer.apple.com/news/rss/news.rss"
    NSMutableString *finalURLStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString: kURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *receivedData = nil;
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: finalURLStr]
                                      cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                  timeoutInterval: 60.0];
    receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                         returningResponse: &response
                                                     error: &error];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];

    parser.delegate = self;
    self.channelFlag = -1;
    self.mutableData = [NSMutableString new];
    if (![parser parse]) {
        // Handle Parse XML Failed
    }
    NSLog(@"channel = %@", self.channel);
    return YES;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    //reset buffer memory
    [self.mutableData setString:@""];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {
        self.channel = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        self.channelFlag = IsChannel;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        self.item = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        if (!self.items) {
            self.items = [NSMutableArray new];
        }
        self.channelFlag = IsItem;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"atom:link"]) {
        self.channel[@"atomLink"] = attributeDict;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    // elementName exist in channel and item
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        if (self.channelFlag == IsChannel) {
            self.channel[@"title"] = [self.mutableData copy];
        }
        if (self.channelFlag == IsItem) {
            self.item[@"title"] = [self.mutableData copy];
        }
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        if (self.channelFlag == IsChannel) {
            self.channel[@"link"] = [self.mutableData copy];
        }
        if (self.channelFlag == IsItem) {
            self.item[@"link"] = [self.mutableData copy];
        }
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        if (self.channelFlag == IsChannel) {
            self.channel[@"description"] = [self.mutableData copy];
        }
        if (self.channelFlag == IsItem) {
            self.item[@"description"] = [self.mutableData copy];
        }
    }
    // elementName only exist in channel
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"language"]) {
            self.channel[@"language"] = [self.mutableData copy];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastBuildDate"]) {
        self.channel[@"lastBuildDate"] = [self.mutableData copy];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"generator"]) {
        self.channel[@"generator"] = [self.mutableData copy];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"copyright"]) {
        self.channel[@"copyright"] = [self.mutableData copy];
    }
    // elementName only exist in item
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        self.item[@"pubDate"] = [self.mutableData copy];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"guid"]) {
        self.item[@"guid"] = [self.mutableData copy];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"content:encoded"]) {
        self.item[@"contentEncoded"] = [self.mutableData copy];
    }

    // add item to items
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [self.items addObject:self.item];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {
        self.channel[@"items"] = self.items;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    [self.mutableData appendString:string];
}

@end
```